# Nextcord connecting to a Wavelink 2 Node

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

So I'm trying to make my own discord music bot using nextcord and the wavelink method, but I'm currently stuck on connecting to the free hosted lavalink servers. I'm using wavelink 2 and I cannot for the life of me get the wavelink.Node() function to connect to any of them.

```
async def node_connect():
   await bot.wait_until_ready()
   node = wavelink.Node(uri = 'https://lavalink.devamop.in:443', password='DevamOP')
   await wavelink.NodePool.connect(client = bot, nodes = [node])

@bot.event
async def on_wavelink_node_ready(node: wavelink.Node):
   print(f"Node {node.identifier} is ready!")
```

The error I'm currently getting is:

> An error occurred connecting to node: "Node: id="KcRiDLegFHy2",
> uri="http://lavalink.devamop.in:443", status=NodeStatus.CONNECTING".
> 400, message='Invalid response status',
> url=URL('ws://lavalink.devamop.in:443')

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that when you are trying to connect to a secure SSL lavalink server, you need to give it the **secure=True** attribute. This fixed my issue.

```
   node = wavelink.Node(uri = 'https://eu-lavalink.lexnet.cc:443', 
   password='lexn3tl@val!nk', secure=True)
```